# Why would I want to use the Function global constructor?

Tags: javascript, function, security

I'm learning about JavaScript, and in an overview of functions, I noticed the function constructor, ex:`new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b')`.  During the design and debugging, I couldn't imagine why I would need a function constructor, when I can just declare a function in the console or my .js file. My assumption is that the function constructor is meant to face the user, or be accessible on the front end. If this is the case, doesn't the function constructor pose a security vulnerability?

I feel like I'm missing something important here.

Comment: The [function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) is a hidden form of [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). It has its use cases, ex. including functions in JSON data comes to mind. Or rather extracting functions included in JSON data.

Comment: Its a security concern if you can manipulate function definition in this case it should be fine as a and b and function body is defined..